# get nary a nod -- what does this mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [CompTIA A+ Certification All-in-One Exam Guide, 9th Edition (Exam 220-901 & 220-902) by Mike Meyers (2016)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/125958951X)

Example:

> Focus here on what you can do with every OS and you’ll be able to handle any distro easily. Finally, Google Chrome OS, used on Google’s line of portable computers (Chromebooks), **gets nary a nod**.

What exactly does this expression mean? The word *nary* by itself means *not*, but you wouldn't say "gets not a nod" as that just doesn't sound like proper English.

Comment: You could not find this in an online dictionary?  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> nar·y adjective informal or dialect form of not. "nary a murmur or
>   complaint"

Google dictionary

**Nary a nod** is a colloquial expression meaning it was hardly noticed. "He walked by me and gave **nary a nod**, as if he did not know me at all."

So,  Google Chrome OS is barely/hardly mentionable. Unless I am out of context and it means the opposite -- "I need not mention that Google Chrome OS, works well."

Answer (score 2):

I wold add that while a lot of people might understand "nary a nod," it is decidedly old-fashioned sounding. It is not a commonly used phrase at all.

As to the meaning in that situation, I couldn't say without more context.  It could mean that no one considers it when ranking OS's, for instance.